# How to automatically reload a single modified window in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I found [this question and the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/274961/how-to-automatically-reload-modified-files-in-notepad), which shows the setting for Notepad++ to update changed files without have to click the confirmation button.

However in my case there is a *single file window* that I want to skip the reload file confirmation dialog. The file is a log file that gets overwritten each time my program runs. I do not want other windows to auto-reload because it could lead to inadvertent data loss.

Is there a way to designate auto-reload behavior for one window, but still have the default behavior for other windows?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unless your file is very large, it is possible.

Check menu item **View** > **Monitoring (tail -f)**

- This setting is *per file*, so it will work for your individual file.
- The file is *not editable* when the setting is enabled.
- If you have enabled word wrapping and the file is not always scrolled to end as expected, update Notepad++ to version 7.9 where this issue is fixed.

---

This is a workaround if the above won't satisfy you:

Copy your Notepad++ into another directory, configure global reload settings differently and keep your special file open in that second instance of Notepad++.

- You can even set a different color style for that instance so you can instantly recognize it.
- This is a good choice to keep the file *editable* for certain use cases.

Comment: There's no "Monitor" option in View menu in my case (Notepad++ v6.8.8)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc – but this question was asked when Notepad++ version 7.4.2 was the current one. If you want to ask about version 6.8.8 which was 1.5 years old at time of asking the question, please create separate question.

Comment: The current Notepad++ version is 7.5.1. You didn't mention the version in the post so I assume it's version is irrelevant. The version in my company is very old. I checked mine at home and there is a "Monitoring" menu item there

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc – I'd assume that unless stated differently, all Q&A's are to their dates. So Q was asking about version 7.4.2 and A was on 7.5.1. Of course, comment like "but it cannot be found in version 1.0.0" looks a bit off-topic, this is why I reacted. Have a good day. :)

Comment: this is EXACTLY what i've been looking for. you don't even need to enable "File Status auto-detection"

Answer (score 8):

Click the eyeball on later versions. Currently on 7.5.6 but not sure how far back the eyeball goes.

[image: Picture of the Eyeball icon]